# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS error on start up but keeps on going fine

Tags: 16.04

im new here and new to ubuntu 16.04 lts.
I just bought a new lenovo 310-15 laptop with intel i3 6100u cpu 8gb ram and nvidia gt 920 mx gpu. At first i installed dual boot and had windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04 and everything worked just fine,two days later  decided that i dont need windows 10. Erased everything and installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS after first restart it showed

:"platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1"

:"MSFT0101:00: platfprm device creation failed: -"

/dev/sda1: clean, 198582/30007296 files, 6133617/120023296 blocks

and it kept showing this everythime i turn on my laptop...
i mean it works fine when it gets over that, but i want to fix it.

Comment: This is the closest I could find to your error messages: [https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2314378]

Answer (score 1):

MSFT0101 is an ACPI object and refers to Intel Platform Trust Technology (Intel PTT).  It seems that the kernel platform driver (drivers/bases/platform.c) cannot add this device to the device hierarchy because the ACPI IO or memory spaces resources could not be claimed. Not sure if this is because of a firmware configuration issue or more probably because there is no driver support for this.  Either way, unless you are wanting to use Intel PTT, this is error message can be probably ignored.

The /dev/sda1: clean, 198582/30007296 files, 6133617/120023296 blocks message is just the result of checking partition /dev/sda1 on boot and it's some message cruft appearing on the console and can be ignored too.